# AJAX/jQuery project viewer

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Lately I've seen a lot of cool portfolio "AJAX project viewers" in WordPress with jQuery.
For example:
http://demo.designerthemes.com/prolio/portfolio/

http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/

I've been searching for hours on Google to find some tutorials on how to build a cool AJAX project viewer, but couldn't find one. I would love to implement this on my portfolio!

I know a lot of these scripts are custom made, but anybody who knows if there are some tutorials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Learn about Javascript, CSS, HTML, Ajax, and you are done to do this.

Comment: You can find HTML, jQ, AJAX tutorials on google.

Comment: Generally Stack Overflow doesn't find tutorials or help provide out-of-the-box solutions.  We're more on the topic of helping with specific issues with code, such as if you were implementing this effect and were stuck on a particular piece of the implementation.  That being said, I don't know of any particular solutions for this and agree that these look custom-made.  However, one should be able to decompose the individual aspects of each implementation and re-create them one at a time.  With a little practice and a little polish, it shouldn't be terribly difficult.

Comment: What I often do is look at what JavaScript files are being loaded, either by viewing page source, or something like firebug. Then google the site that hosts it, if it's a jquery plugin say. Or if it's totally custom, it might have comments

Answer (score 2):

This particular example uses [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), a jQuery plugin.

There's a tutorial here that talks about how you might do the integration http://rollyourowncreative.com/2011/09/using-isotope-jquery-plugin-in-wordpress-a-better-way-to-implement-isotope-in-wordpress/

A more suitable search would be "ajax in wordpress", and treat the tasks of UI (JS behaviours) and retrieving posts (the Ajax bit) separately.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for tutorials for the viewer (after you've clicked a project), not the filtering ;).

Comment: Either way...  my point here is to break down the task at hand to concoct a solution. 1. Figure out how to retrieve posts via Ajax 2. Get to grips with a plugin (e.g. isotope, or whatever is relevant to the viewer) or write some code that deals with how users interact with the page